# Dates in android studio (kotlin)

Tags: datepicker

I am using a datepicker in my app, the date from the date picker is calculated in milliseconds, now i want to add 55 days to that date and the final date to be in milliseconds, how can i go about doing that?
Many Thanks

`year = date_picker.year`
`month = date_picker.month`
`day = date_picker.dayOfMonth`
`val calendar = GregorianCalendar(year, month, day, 0, 0, 0)` var millis = calendar.timeInMillis`